# How to use Emotiv EPOC or Ambient TheAudeo with Ableton Live?

Tags: ableton-live

[image: headset]
[image: dongle]

I know C/Java/Python and I want to make a plug-in for Ableton Live. **Is this possible and where to start?**

I found some software chain on the Emotiv forums: MindYourOSCs -> PD -> MidiYoke -> Ableton Live
So what is PD?

Comment: I can't figure out what it is that you're asking.

Comment: I fixed your image markup, but I'm not sure they add anything to your question.

Comment: I like the idea of making music with EPOC or other devices and want to share it (easy to understand with images) because SE is great!

Comment: It just seems like a really spammy way to approach your question. All you are asking is "how do I interface this hardware with Ableton Live, ideally via a plugin." The actual device is secondary to the question, but you give it top billing.

Comment: From Barcelona, what about emotive epoc and ableton,does it's work?

Comment: If Emotiv wasn't so pricey with their SDK, I'd write the code for you.  Sorry!  I signed up for their developer program awhile back for $300, and in the end I think they wanted $15,000.  I ended up writing something for the OCZ NIA (http://www.musatcha.com/software/MindMasterMIDI/) instead, but that hardware isn't available anymore.  Best of luck!

Comment: @user5283: Nothing done yet. But got Ableton Push. It's fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a plugin for Ableton, you need to look up [VST plugins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Studio_Technology).

PD is [Pure Data](http://puredata.info), a free modular MIDI and audio processing environment. PD is similar to [Max/MSP](http://cycling74.com/products/max/), which directly integrates into Live via [Max4Live](https://www.ableton.com/en/live/max-for-live/).